# Order of command execution when using file.append and file.managed with salt states

Tags: saltstack

I am managing the `main.cf` config file in my postfix sls. If the same minion has also assigned the amavis state, the line `content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024`should be appended to the managed `main.cf` file.

My **postfix sls** looks like this:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
  file.managed:
    - template: jinja
    - source: salt://postfix/files/etc/postfix/main.cf
```

And in my **amavis sls**, I try to append said line with:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf-amavis:
  file.append:
    - name: /etc/postfix/main.cf
    - text: "content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024"
    - require_in:
      - file: /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

However, `append` happens before `manage` instead of executing it vice-versa.

```
Name: /etc/postfix/main.cf - Function: file.append - Result: Changed
Name: /etc/postfix/main.cf - Function: file.managed - Result: Changed
```

What is the proper way to append contents to a managed file? Or is there another way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `require` not `require_in`:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf-amavis:
  file.append:
    - name: /etc/postfix/main.cf
    - text: "content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024"
    - require:
      - file: /etc/postfix/main.cf
```